# Angular with static pages or components? (too much components?)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, components

I have a question about implementing static html pages in to angular 2.
I'm quite new to angular so I was wondering if you guys have an idea for the following question:

I'm building a quite simple web-app by which a teacher can enter 6 different lessons.
The user has an account environment where he can add classes (as real school classes) and view the progress of the classes.

So within each class the teacher can start these 6 different lessons which content is pure static and is almost like slides of a powerpoint.
I was thinking about making components for each slide, but there are almost 70 slides. So maybe the app gets really slow of it?

If i just add them as plain html pages then i need the last page to redirect to a angular component where the teacher can input data in an input[type=text] element. But i was wondering: How can i direct from a plain html to the angular component? Don't know if that's even possible?

Now my question is if you guys think of a good way to add this 'slides' within the app.

Shall I just make a lot of components for each slide? Or do you have an other recommendation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you make the contents of the slides dynamic?, Create a single component and read the contents from a service, or simple JSON file. Then build the construct the layout of the slide from the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create on component, maybe `display-slide`, and for each slide use a service, `get-slide` to fetch the slide data from a database, and display it in the component.

and yes, you can let the teacher enter data in and input tag: `<input type="text" name="className" value="">` and use either template driven or reactive forms to gather that data, and send it to the database with a service.

*creating a component for each slide *will slow down* your app, and It is probably not a great idea to let the user essentially create a component. using a database with services will be very little code, and make your app faster. the requests are asyncronous, but the result will be better

Comment: @Maarten awesome, if you feel this answered your question, feel free to mark it as the answer. otherwise let me know of any clarifications